# DatePicker is not a function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am having a problme with datepicker not being a function. I researched it and it sounds like the common problem is you are implmenting to Jqueries, but I only have one line importing jquery.

```html
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery/loadMe.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery/datePicker.js"></script>
```

HTML code:

```
<label for="date">Date</label>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="date-picker">
```

JQuery code in datePicker.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker();
})
```

Error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Datepicker is **jQuery UI**, not part of jQuery itself.

Comment: You can use input-type "date" for picking a date. As it is available in almost all browser nowadays. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp

Comment: Are you have datePicker.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is [**jQuery UI**](https://jqueryui.com/), not part of *jQuery itself*.

So you need to load the jQuery UI library after jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="date-picker" />
```

You may also want to use one of the [jQuery UI skin themes](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="date-picker" />
```

Comment: Can I not include that in my jquery file? It doesn't work if I do

Comment: No, jQuery UI is a separate thing. Why would you not simply include a 2nd script?

Comment: I updated my code I copied everything you put and same error :O

Comment: Well, what can I say, you see it works here, should work for you as well.